# MySql in Xampp do not start

Tags: wordpress

I have changed the port number in my MySQL config as well as my current working project's wp-config file.
However, in the MySQL config, I am unable to save it, and an error occurs, saying "Cannot create 'E:\xampp\xampp-control.ini'. Access is denied." Why does this happen?

Another approach I tried is as follows:

- Go to the XAMPP folder -> MySQL.
- In the MySQL folder, rename the 'data' folder to 'data_old.'
- Create a new 'data' folder.
- Copy all files from the backup folder and paste them into the newly created 'data' folder.
- Copy the 'mysql' and 'created' databases from 'data_old' and paste them into the 'data' folder.

After following these steps, MySQL starts. However, I am not able to log in to my currently working project in WordPress. How can I resolve these MySQL issues so that I can work on my current project again?

Another ways that I tried is follow above step : Go to xampp folder -> mysql then in mysql folder I rename data folder as data_old and created a new data folder then copy all files of backup folder and paste it in newly created data folder then copied mysql and created databases from data_old and paste it in the data folder. after follow these process mysql start. But I am not able to login to my currently working project again. how to resolved thses mysql issue so that I can able to work on my current working project again in wordpress